# Expose only Docker Swarm Manager nodes to the internet. Keep workers hidden (no public IP)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is there a way to make "worker" nodes hidden from the Internet through some clever port forwarding/hiding/exposing?

My goal is to create a Docker Swarm of some public IP manager nodes and A LOT of worker nodes that will be hidden in our company infrastructure. Given that the company infrastructure is accessible through a single IP from the outside world, but the workers themselves are multiple - naturally, I can not give each worker a distinct public IP.

I was wondering what are the ways to tackle this challenge from an infrastructure standpoint?

Comment: inststall a reverse proxy /load balancer on the Docker swarm manager (or maybe on another machine that does the forwarding)

Comment: @jonathanHeindl could you please elaborate? Or point me to an example/article that describes the process as an overview?

Comment: nginx install example
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart
load balancer setup:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html
there is also a dockerized version of nginx that works practically the same

Comment: th ebasic idea is to have one access point (port 443(maybe 80)) on the host machine and proxy pass everything to the nodes then only allow access to port 443 of the host by your firewall